# Combination of ? and ?? in an expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-to-vb.net

```
string value = ( expression ? expression ?? string: string.Method())
```

Not sure how to unwrap this. Can anyone help?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: As it is, this is invalid - you can't use `string` like this. Please change the example to be one which will actually compile.

Comment: Also, if you can't understand it now, that points to difficult to maintain code. Just don't do it.

Answer (score 4):

The outside operator is: `? :`, or the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx). It is a one-line `if` statement.

```
if (expression)
   first;
else
   second;
```

Can be replaced by:

```
expression ? first : second;
```

The inner operator, `??`, or the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) simply returns the value itself, *if* it is not `null`, or the other value if the value *is* `null`.

```
x ?? y;
```

Is the same as (commonly represented using the ternary operator in older code):

```
x != null ? x : y;
```

So, your entire statement (once made valid, as I assumed the parameters of the statement were not meant to be taken literally):

```
string value;

if (expression1)
{
    value = expression2 ?? "some string";
    /*
    if (expression2 != null)
    {
        value = expression2;
    }
    else
    {
        value = "some string";
    }
    */
}
else
{
    value = someMethod();
}
```

Comment: The name of ?: is the *conditional* operator. It happens to be a ternary operator, as it has three operands - and it happens to be the only one, but that's not its *name*.

Comment: @Jon You know, I've called it the ternary operator for years and never realized I was doing it out of the bad habit that it was the only one. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

The example is invalid, but let's pretend it *was* valid, and just reformat it:

```
string value = (
 expression ?   // expression determines which branch to take
                expression ?? string // Null coalescing operator
            : string.Method() // Alternative branch of conditional operator
               );
```

Now, do you know about the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) and the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) separately? If so, this should all be clear by now...

Answer (score 0):

In C#, a ? b : c is short for if a then b else c.

a ?? b is short for "if a == null then return b else return a." If you know SQL, think "ISNULL" operator.

I'm going to assume that "string" isn't the type but some sort of constant string.

```
if (expression1)
{
    if (expression2 != null)
        value = expression2
    else
        value = string1
}
else
{
    value = string2.Method();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, as you have expression being both a boolean and string and you can't use string the way you are, but this is what it would be in a more verbose way

```
string value;
if(expression)
{
  if(expressionStr != null)
    value = expressionStr;
  else
    value = string.Empty;
}
else
{
  value = string.Method(); // Don't know what this is supposed to be
}
```

Comment: Woops, you beat me to it. Same answer. I'll delete mine!